# mysql - calculating columns(2 columns with numbers) based on another group of column(text)

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns, calculation

Hi I would like to find a query for the below, I am trying to calculate data between two columns however based on another column which needs to be a selected group of the same values

Unfiltered

Start Time________Disconnect Time______Signalling IP

12:59:00.3________13:26:03.3___________1.1.1.1

10:59:00.3________11:03:03.3___________2.2.2.2

19:59:00.3________20:02:03.3___________1.1.1.1

Filtered

Start Time________Disconnect Time______Signalling IP

12:59:00.3________13:26:03.3___________1.1.1.1

19:59:00.3________20:02:03.3___________1.1.1.1

If you see the table above, I want the selected IP only which is 1.1.1.1, and then from there, calculate the total duration of time from the Start Time and Disconnect Time for that Egress IP.

So column 3 has multiple values, however I need to select the same value, then from there calculate the sum of column 1 and 2 based on column 3.

Please let me know if you have anything in mind, as I have tried multiple queries but can't get the correct one

Comment: it would be a lot easier if you could give a minimum example - data structure and some rows and what you expect

Comment: Hi sorry, I have added in the picture, please let me know if that would help

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected output as text to the question.

Comment: Hi @P.Salmon kindly please see the modified question, I have added the sample data and what needs to be done

Comment: We can't use images (and some of us won't type them) - text is better

Comment: Please see the updated question, I think that should be much better? @P.Salmon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to calculate difference between to times.
you can use time_to_sec to convert each time value to seconds
and subtract start time from end time to get time period in seconds.
you cat turn it back to time format with SEC_TO_TIME
example

```
select
column3,
SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(column2) - TIME_TO_SEC(column1))
from 
table 
group by column3
```

Comment: hi thank you so much, however how would I filter column 3 so that it is the same set of values, and I would like to calculate the difference in times, I will try that now and let you know

Comment: use where column3 = "uer ip"

Comment: I am getting value of 1030157, what output would that be?

Comment: Hi, yes I have used that command, however I took the total time and used https://www.convertworld.com/en/time/seconds.html to convert seconds to hours, or minutes etc. or is the output that I am getting shouldn't be like that?

Comment: there something wrong in your sql query 
please post this part of query

Comment: Hi sorry, i see for one of them I put time_to_sec and the other I put sec_to_time, I now put time_to sec and I am getting 234 seconds which is around 3 minutes

Comment: Can I by any chance have the decimal time there as well, like HH:MM::SS.s?

Comment: pass this output to sec_to_time will convert to time format

Comment: I just did that, however I am now getting a value of 837, so I am not sure how it is interpreting the data in which the format is (HH:MM:SS)

Comment: use it as this select sec_to_time(  TIME_TO_SEC("12:00:00") - TIME_TO_SEC("10:00:00") )

Comment: Hi Emad, thank you so much for your help, this has worked, however I have not used the previous example you have given me, but I have used the initial one. Much appreciated.